# How to identify if ObjectInputStream has available object?

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

Getting error `NullPointerException` while trying to identify if serialized object is available and receive it using socket. How to identify if `ObjectInputStream` has available object?
Firs off I try to read a text then try to read from the same socket Lot object ()which may not be there.

```
        public class ThreadIn extends Thread{
        BufferedReader in;
            PrintStream outConsole;
            Socket socket;
            ObjectInputStream ois;
            String str;
            Lot lot;
ThreadIn(BufferedReader input, PrintStream inOutput, Socket s){
        str = "";
        in= input;
        socket= s;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        outConsole = inOutput;

    }
    public void run() {

            while(!EXIT_THREAD){
            try {
        if(in.ready()){
            try {
                str= in.readLine();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                EXIT_THREAD= true;
                break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                outConsole.println("Received:"+str);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            try {
                if((Lot)ois.readObject() != null){      
                    lot = (Lot)ois.readObject(); 
                    if (lot!=null){outConsole.println(lot.toString());} 
                    outConsole.println((String)ois.readObject());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((Lot)ois.readObject() != null)
```

this part itself reads the object from Socket., So you are reading 3 times the object from Socket in your code. If you have only one Object coming in the socket, or more, you can read the object and catch the exception!.
Just like below

```
 //..loop start
         try {
                lot = (Lot)ois.readObject(); 
             }
         catch (Exception e) 
           { 
//      do some handling, skip the object! put a continue: or something

            }
    //do what ever you want to do with `lot`

    //..loop end
```

and now, as per your code, you have not initialized your `ObjectInputStream` Object.

Do a `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());`

If you omitted the code here, well my mistake, else pls do initialize the socket also!

Comment: Code updated. I try to initialize in Thread constructor. It is a good practice to use *try catch* in constructor?

Comment: Just read the Object in a try - catch. Catch a general exception, since NUllPointerException shall not be captured as per coding standards. I think this should work.

Comment: There is no mistake in using try-catch in a constructor, but do not leave your catch block just for stackTrace, that is bad :). Do some good handling actions over there, put some logs. or something that would make a Exception "nice" :D

Comment: can I compare like that: *if(ois.readObject() instanceof Lot)* ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the other answers, including the deleted ones, you are calling `readObject()` twice and throwing the first result away. You should reorganize your code so it can block in `readObject()`.

You have other problems. You are testing the result of `readObject()` for `null?`, but it only returns `null` if you wrote a `null` at the sender. I suspect you are using this as an EOS test, but it is invalid. `readObject()` throws `EOFException` at EOS. You should reorganize your code so it can block in `readObject()`.